# How to get email address with google access token?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

I'm not able to get the email id from the Response
Here the Response:

```
{
  "id": "00000000000000",
  "name": "Fred Example",
  "given_name": "Fred",
  "family_name": "Example",
  "picture": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-2Sv-4bBMLLA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABo/bEG4kI2mG0I/photo.jpg",
  "locale": "en"
}
```

and this is what I'm using:

`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=' + token`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need a different scope. According to documentation, the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile` allows you to see basic profile info. In order to see the e-mail, you need this scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir, Now I'm getting the e-mail address.

Comment: Now i'm able to get the email , Below is the Response
`"{
  "id": "00000000000000",
  "email":"abc.xyz.com",
  "name": "Fred Example",
  "given_name": "Fred",
  "family_name": "Example",
  "picture": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-2Sv-/photo.jpg",
  "locale": "en"
}"`   , and using this response how to retrive the email?

Comment: `var email = JSON.parse(response)["email"];`

Comment: @IvánNokonoko Hi, I'm also having same issie. While using `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email.` I'm getting  response as "userinfo.email". Please help

Comment: @Gowri `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` is not the API endpoint, but the scope. The API endpoint, to which you have to send your authorised requests is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo`.

Comment: @Gowri I am trying to connect with this address and still not getting the email  [link](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=SOMETOKEN&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email)

Comment: You are receiving this error either because your input OAuth2 scope name is invalid or it refers to a newer scope that is outside the domain of this legacy API.

This API was built at a time when the scope name format was not yet standardized. This is no longer the case and all valid scope names (both old and new) are catalogued at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes. Use that webpage to lookup (manually) the scope name associated with the API you are trying to call and use it to craft your OAuth2 request. THIS IS MY LAST RESPONSE

Answer (score 0):

Now i'm able to get the email in respone, below is the code, where i changed the Response in the manifest

```
"oauth2": {
"client_id": "854569859639-9c0reicivklkv0ltpakv99iajqts5obs.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "scopes": [ "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" ]}
```

i changd the scope `"scopes": [ "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" ]` to
 `"scopes": [ "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" ]`

and below is the response

```
 "{
  "id": "00000000000000",
  "name": "Fred Example",
  "email":"abc@xyz.com",
  "given_name": "Fred",
  "family_name": "Example",
  "picture": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-2Sv-4bBMLLA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABo/bEG4kI2mG0I/photo.jpg",
  "locale": "en"
}"
```

Comment: For me not getting response as "userinfo.email". Please help